# Can a SharePoint Filtered Lookup pass Multiple Values to act as an Or/And

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I have a simple list that I have built a lookup tool for which I ask on a form for part of the users name and a drop down for the record type.

lets say the user is in the list 3 times

```
UserName    UserType
Joe         Approver
Joe         Advisor
Joe         Tester
```

Since I pass the values from the form to the display code as parms, username is parm1 and type is parm2

When I setup the filter I want to create a way so the selection of a specific value works which it does and the ability to select all and have all work.

[image: filter]

[image: form dropdown setup]